# why float drop?

Tags: css, css-float

I have a simple css layout

```
wrapper
header
left-sidebar / main-content / right-sidebar
footer
```

but my main content seems to drop (float drop) and I don't understand why.

I have set it up in a fiddle  - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krutski/rZpfj/)

I can get it to not drop by removing the `float:left` from the `main-content` div but I don't understand why this is so. The container (wrapper) has a float:left and I thought this was the way to avoid the 'float drop'

I am float:left on the left-sidebar and wrapper so I thought the main-content would just simply line up with the left-sidebar if I set float:left on the main-content div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#main-content` div needs a proper measurement value.

```
#main-content
{
margin-left: 110px;
margin-right: 110px;
float:left;
padding-bottom:150px;
width:500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the right and left margins from the `main-content` div, you'll see how it behaves normally (as it ought to) with a float applied to it. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rZpfj/12/)

It's too wide to fit alongside the sidebar in the parent, so it drops down.

However, I think the problem is you have the width of `main-content` set to `500p`, change that to `500px.` [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rZpfj/13/)